GPU is not recognized with Custom Image Docker - Google Vertex AI
Good morning, I'm having a problem running a custom job, I'm getting an image from docker hub, from nvidia
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.4.1-base-ubuntu20.04

From there, I place the settings for my project. Then I follow the steps in the documentation. When I'm going to send a job, with the cli. The job is executed, it passes all the steps, but it fails to use or find the GPU.
gcloud ai custom-jobs create --region=xxxxx --display-name=xxx123 --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=n1-standard-4,accelerator-type=NVIDIA_TESLA_T4,container-image-uri=xxxxx --args=xx,xxx-job-train,xxxxx


I hope to be able to run my container using the GPU to carry out training

Have you tried with Google Cloud Deep Learning containers? https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/choosing-container Example: us-docker.pkg.dev/deeplearning-platform-release/gcr.io/base-cu121.py310

I haven't tested them yet. I will follow the link, check if I am successful. Thanks for the guidance

I was trying to create a custom container. Using images from docker hub.
https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/#!
I tried as in the documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/containers-overview
But I will follow your alternative

Thanks, @gogasca . It worked with this alternative.
